# cartesian product of two metric spaces separable if and only if each of them is separable

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ be two nonempty metric spaces. We consider in $X\times Y$ the metric $d_{\infty}$ defined as $\max\{d(x_1,x_2),d'(y_1,y_2)\}$. Prove that $(X\times Y,d_{\infty})$ is separable if and only if $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are separable.

I could prove that if the two metric are separable, then the cartesian product is separable. What I did to prove it was: We know that $X$ and $Y$ are separable, so take $E$ and $E'$ dense countable sets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Let's prove that $E\times E'$ is a dense countable. $\operatorname{cl}(E\times E')=\operatorname{cl}(E)\times\operatorname{cl}(E')=X\times Y$.

I don't know how to prove the other implication.

Comment: You need to assume that neither space is empty, otherwise the conclusion is wrong. Can you prove that a subspace of a separable metric space is separable?

Comment: But if the two spaces happen to be empty, then they are trivially separable and their product is separable. If one of the two is empty and the other is non-empty, I don't see why the conclusion is wrong.

Comment: If one of the two spaces is empty and the other not separable, the product is empty, hence separable.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my post and add the nonemptyness condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ is the dense subset of $X\times Y$ and $\pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ are projection. We will prove that $\pi_X(A)$ is dense subset in $X$. Let $V$ is open subset of $X$, then $V\times Y$ is open subset of $X\times Y$. Since $A$ is dense subset of $X\times Y$ so $V\times Y$ contains some element of $A$, so $\pi_X(V\times Y)=V$ contain the some elements in $\pi_X(A)$. Similarly you can prove that $\pi_Y(A)$ is dense subset of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be dense in $X\times Y$ and let $E'$ be its projection to $X$. Then $E'$ is dens in $X$ because for any nonempty open set $U$ of $X$, there is a point of $E$ in the nonempty open set $U\times Y$ of $X\times Y$, hence a point of $E'$ in $U$.